# "window" global scope in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

In a normal browser window, one can reference the "window" object to access global variables.

That doesn't seem to work in phonegap however. Is there a way to access a "window"-like global variable in phonegap?

My goal is something like:

```
var events = function(data) { console.log(data); }   
window['events']('hello world');
> hello world
```

Thanks

Comment: is the above code snippet not working in PhoneGap? PhoneGap does not do anything in particular to the window object other than maybe adding some properties to it.

Comment: Yeah, I was somewhat surprised as well. At least in the iPhone simulator the above snippet doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you looking for in the window object?

As the many different devices have different properties, a lot of them are pulled into the phonegap specific variables (http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_device_device.md.html)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't particularly clear. Edited my question to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: I can't see why 'window' shouldn't be there, but as a matter of clarity, we add our own variable in the first line of JS of every page instead of using the window object. var OWN_WINDOW; will give you an object to work with all the same. Hopefully someone can give you a better answer than that!